# Spring autowire using annotations and a type defined in a properties file?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, dependency-injection, annotations

My goal is a framework where concrete types of beans can be easily changed by a properties file. I also prefer annotations to XML. Ideally I'd to use a combination of `@Resource` and SpEL like this:

```
@Resource(type="#{myProperties['enabled.subtype']}")
SomeInterface foo;
```

where I've loaded `myProperties` with a `PropertiesFactoryBean` or `<util:properties>` from a file that includes:

```
enabled.type = com.mycompany.SomeClassA; // which implements SomeInterface
```

This doesn't work because the argument of `type` must be a literal, i.e., no SpEL allowed. What's the best practice here?

**Update:** See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the use case for Spring Java Configuration.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java

Or you can alternatively make a Factory.

Using: org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean<SomeInterface>

The name of the bean that implements FactoryBean will be seen as a "SomeInterface" even though its not.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible, the solution I tend to adopt is to use a factory that creates the different objects depending on a configuration property (enabled.type in your example).

A second alternative could be to use injection by name:

```
@Resource(name="beanName")
```

And last, if you use Spring 3.1+ you can try to use profiles, and have different bean sets in different profiles, if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Spring's Java Configuration](http://blog.springsource.org/2006/11/28/a-java-configuration-option-for-spring/) and [Bean Definition Profiles](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/) turn out to be exactly what I was looking for (thanks @Adam-Gent and @Guido-Garcia). The former seems necessary for the dynamic element, and the latter promotes a better practice.

Here's a solution with Java config and properties:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeClassConfig {
    @Value("#{myProperties['enabled.subtype']}")
    public Class enabledClass;

    @Bean SomeInterface someBean() 
              throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
       return (SomeInterface) enabledClass.newInstance();
    }   
}
```

Here's a slightly less dynamic solution with profiles.

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class DevelopmentConfig {
    @Bean SomeInterface someBean() {
       return new DevSubtype();
    }   
}

@Configuration
@Profile("prod")
public class ProductionConfig {
    @Bean SomeInterface someBean() {
       return new ProdSubtype();
    }   
}
```

With profiles, the active profile(s) are declared using one of a [variety of methods](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/) such as via system property, JVM property, web.xml, etc. For example, with a JVM property:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active="dev"
```

Comment: If you get lazy consider @Bean(autowire=Autowire.BY_TYPE).